# Problem Generating Azure ADLS Gen2 SAS Token for Container with Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

From azure.storage.blob I'm using the function generate_container_sas. I'm trying to generate a SAS token for a container in an ADLS Gen2 storage account in Azure. I can go into azure portal and generate a working SAS token using an account key with no issues. The token works just fine. However, when I do what I think is the same thing in python I get a token back but when I load it into storage explorer it says "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.". I have validated all the inputs appear to be correct. The token that is generated looks like:

https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT>.blob.core.windows.net/<CONTAINER_NAME>?se=2022-02-19T05%3A41%3A26Z&sp=rwdlac&sv=2020-10-02&sr=c&sig=jCd8AAatl5o9QsbMHtlca6oNnnRdKqtcOnWN3sZa1c8%3D

```
        sas_token = generate_container_sas(
        account_name=account_name,
        container_name=container_name,
        account_key=account_key,
        permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True, list=True, write=True, delete=True, create=True, add=True),
        expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=expiry_hours)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are using `AccountSasPermissions` instead of [`ContainerSasPermissions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containersaspermissions?view=azure-python). Can you try by changing the following line of code:

```
permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True, list=True, write=True, delete=True, create=True, add=True),
```

to

```
permission=ContainerSasPermissions(read=True, list=True, write=True, delete=True),
```